# Треугольная форма WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как сделать треугольную форму xaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Window.AllowsTransparency значение true.
2. Window.WindowStyle значение None
3. Установите для фона (свойства Background) прозрачный цвет (цвет Transparent, значение альфа-канала которого равно нулю). Или же сделайте так, чтобы для фона использовалось изображение, имеющее прозрачные области (с нулевым значением альфа-канала).

Эти три шага эффективно удаляют стандартный внешний вид окна. Для обеспечения эффекта окна необычной формы далее необходимо предоставить какое-то непрозрачное содержимое, имеющее нужную форму.

Источник: [Окна нестандартной формы](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level23/23_5.php).